# How to generate OAuth 2.0 token using TOTP?

Tags: python, azure, oauth-2.0

[image]Have this code in python:

```
import pyotp

totp = pyotp.TOTP('secret')

otp = totp.now()
```

How can I use otp generated above as a request parameter in the below API call to retrieve the OAuth2 token?

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant-ID%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass "otp"- value into the body of `POST` request as a part of payload with others like `client_id, secret` etc.  and request for the token, the token was generated.

The `data` in the code are the params I took it from azure.

Find the below code for your reference.

```
import sys
import pyotp
import json
import requests 

secret = 'base32secret'    
totp = pyotp.TOTP(secret)
otp = totp.now()

API_ENDPOINT = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token"

headers = {
"Content-type": "application/json",
}  
data = {
'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
'username': 'someusrname',
'client_id': 'client_id',
'client_secret':'client_secret',
'scope':'api://{applicationId}/.default',
'otp': otp,
}

res = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = data)
print("Access token is:", res.text)
```

[image]

Note: Make sure Oauth 2.0 is enabled to get the `scope`. How to enable it, check it out [here](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/requests/auth/types/oauth2/tutorial-azure.html)